# OpenCV Suddenly not working on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: opencv, osx-mountain-lion

I just updated my Xcode to 4.6 and then I noticed that my installed OpenCV does not working properly. I got the following errors when I was trying to compile conde that uses OpenCV:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that Google knows how to fix this problem.

Comment: I tried Google, but could not find any solution that works.
This is a similar problem 
http://mac-os-forge.2317878.n4.nabble.com/Incorrect-libjpeg-dylib-after-installing-ImageMagick-td134968.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[This is the answer](http://player-stage-gazebo.10965.n7.nabble.com/dyld-Symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart-td18281.html) you are looking for.*

Set environment variable `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like just source ~/.profile will not work. After rebooting the computer, it worked!